# Iterating over a list and calling directives depending upon the item types , in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a HTML file it iterates over a list of objects as shown and every object has a template( stored in the db) that it uses I get "List" from a web service :-

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="object in List"  ng-include="object.TemplateName" > </li> 
</ul>

Let object.TemplateName be "template1"
```

A sample template would have a specific directive with the attributes needed and few html tags as shown "template1":-

```
template1:-

<directive1 s-web-service-path="object.WebServicePath" >

<h1>any html content</h1>

</directive1>
```

my directive calls a web service to get the content to be displayed and has its own template... instead of putting directives in a template and including them cant I directly call my directive depending upon the different types of objects that i obtain in List
something like

for Object.Type="1"  i call directive1  instead of template1
for Object.Type="2"  i call directive2  instead of template2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngIf or ngSwitch might be helpful here, with a few extra wrapping elements within the ngRepeat, in order to dynamically choose what to include based on Object.Type. Using ngSwitch:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="object in List">
    <div ng-switch="object.Type">
      <div ng-switch-when="'1'">
        <div ng-include="object.TemplateName"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="'2'">
        <directive1 s-web-service-path="object.WebServicePath" >
        <h1>any html content</h1>
        </directive1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

The above is not tested, so there could potentially be an error. You might also be able to cut down on some of DOM nesting level by including the ng-switch-when attributes on the directive1 / ng-include divs, but the way above makes the behaviour clear, and avoids any unexpected issues that might arise from having multiple directives work on the same element.